# non UIView animation: animations not playing sometimes, UIView animation: working fine

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimation

Sometimes when I run my app on the device, I guess about 20% of the time, animations such as:

```
[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
[tableView setContentOffset:rect animated:YES];
```

and

```
[viewController0 pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
```

do not animate but instantly change. But animations such as:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
                         // do something
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // do something else
                     }];
```

Work fine. Has this happened to anybody else? Not sure what could be causing it, it only happens on this one app, never happened on any other app and it only happens sometimes. Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

Just want to clarify.

Animations that i create with 'animateWithDuration' work fine.

*Sometimes* animations from cocoa don't play for the entire time the app is running.

Comment: Is it possible you're not calling these methods from the main thread?

Comment: I'd guess your application is using too much CPU and is missing some frames (frameskip) so you can't have the animation playing.

Comment: hwaxxer - yeah I am calling them from the main thread

Comment: If you got your answer than accept any one.. Or still issues than let us know..

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the UIView animation parameters before you push your viewcontroller.

Here's an example:

```
[UIView beginAnimation:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:viewController1.view cache:NO];

[viewController0 pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Not sure if this is right. I dont think setAnimationTransition: and pushViewController:animated: have anything to do with beginAnimation: and commitAnimations.

Comment: Well, it should apply transitions to any UIViews. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it still 'sometimes' doesn't play animations for pushViewController and the others.

Comment: This is pretty old way of using UIView Animations, now modern world developers are using block animations. I would welcome you to the modern world. And no need to use beginAnimations and commitAnimations in the modern world.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the boolean u used. My animation is quite the same but it's working fine:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^(void) {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        pfeil.alpha = 1.00;
         }];
```

thats my code...any questions?

Comment: Yeah, using [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:] works fine. I'm talking about animations on things such as [tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES], [tableView setContentOffset:rect animated:YES] and [viewController0 pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES]. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear

Comment: sorry that I can't help you...you must know I'm still learning in Xcode and table views are not so my topic..hope u understand...I'm sorry

Comment: maybe u should look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a lot of data to load in your VC? if you load your data in main thread it stops all user interactions and UI responses for a while.

Comment: The problem is it stops animations that I don't create for the rest of the time the app is running, not just while data is loaded.