# UIView animations not always working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiview

I've a problem with animations.
When I test the app (in the Simulator or a real iPad), more than one time in two, the animations don't work. Even the transitions between two views.
I tried to display what I want without anims, but the problem is still present on the transitions.

Can you help me 'cause I've really no idea what to do :/
Thanks

```
    -(void)displayWithFrame:(CGRect)f
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         recherche.frame = f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [recherche initSubviews];
                     }];
}
```

A very classical animation ^^

Comment: Post some of your animation code so that people can help diagnose.

Comment: I just did it, but when the animations work, mine work. When it doesn't, mine doesn't

Comment: when is this being called?

Comment: What is it that you _expect_ to happen with that code?

Comment: I want to make my view appear.
Sometime this works (and all the animations in the app work), sometime not (and all the anims in the app doesn't).
I don't need help to animate a view, but to understand how and why this happens.

Comment: It's the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611841/non-uiview-animation-animations-not-playing-sometimes-uiview-animation-workin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was feeding my array and reloadData in the viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear.
I don't know why this caused crashes of animations, but after a lot of test, I'm certain that it was the source of the problem.
I hope it will help someone, someday ^^

Comment: Yup, well, that's why someone asked you when your code was being called.

Comment: I know, but I found this before I read his message. ;)
And my code wasn't called in viewWillAppear.

Comment: You're right of course. If you've tracked down the problem, that's good.